# Why does the author make a new instance of this boost::intrusive_ptr in the destructor of a wrapper class?

Tags: c++, boost, com

I've read an [article about using boost::intrusive_ptr for managing COM objects](http://code-freeze.blogspot.hu/2012/02/using-intrusiveptr-with-com.html). The author shows a wrapper class which takes care of adjusting the smart pointer for the usual COM semantics. This is the class:

```
template <typename T>
class WrapPtr
{
public:
    WrapPtr(boost::intrusive_ptr<T>& ref)
    : m_ref(ref), m_ptr(0)
    {
    }
   
    ~WrapPtr()
    {
        // The second parameter indicates that the reference count should not be incremented
        m_ref = boost::intrusive_ptr(m_ptr, false);
    }
   
    operator T**()
    {
        return &m_ptr;
    }
   
    operator void**()
    {
        // Some COM functions ask for a pointer to void pointer, such as QueryInterface
        return reinterpret_cast<void**>(&m_ptr);
    }
   
private:
    T* m_ptr;
    boost::intrusive_ptr<T> m_ref;
};

template <typename T>
WrapPtr<T> AttachPtr(boost::intrusive_ptr<T>& ref)
{
    return WrapPtr<T>(ref);
}
```

What I don't understand is the destructor. It will discard the current m_ref object (which will lead to a call to `Release` of course), but then he assigns a new intrusive_ptr constructed from the m_ptr member. I don't understand why this is needed in the destructor, since the Wrapper class is holding a copy of the intrusive_ptr, not a reference to it. If the callee changed the pointed object, this change will be lost after the destructor is left. Is this a bug here or am I missing something?

Comment: What I don't understand is why the class' functions return values are based on m_ptr (which is set to NULL at construction), instead of m_ref.

Comment: @TomKnapen this is because the purpose of the Wrapper class is to provide an interface for COM semantics which is passing a pointer-to-pointer and letting the callee set the pointer (note that it's operator T** and void**).

Comment: Am I missing something or does m_ptr never get set?

Comment: @doomster, yes. Read my previous comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a similar "safe address-of" class I once saw, the class had an intrusive_ptr reference (`intrusive_ptr<T>&`), not an actual object (`intrusive_ptr<T>`). The class you posted won't actually affect the client's intrusive_ptr. So it looks like the code is just buggy: it should hold a reference to the client's intrusive_ptr, not a separate intrusive_ptr object:

```
template <typename T>
class WrapPtr
{
private:
    T* m_ptr;
    boost::intrusive_ptr<T>& m_ref;

    ...
};
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to answer your actual question :)

With the fix above, what the destructor does becomes clearer: it sets the client's intrusive_ptr to hold the pointer that was set by calling **operator T**** or **operator void**** and passing it to a "getter" method (e.g. QueryInterface).

Comment: In that case however, the reference count wouldn't be incremented upon the creation of WrapPtr, would it?

Comment: The reference count doesn't need to be incremented for the purposes of this class.